# Change values to one matrix depending on value in corresponding cells in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have two exact same dim matrix such as

```
**matrix1**
  1  2  3  4 
A 1  0  0  1
B 1  0  1  1
C 1  0  1  0
D 0  1  1  0

**matrix2**

  1  2  3  4 
A a  0  0  x
B b  0  x  a
C x  0  a  0
D 0  c  b  0
```

and I would like to transform value to 0 in the `matrix1` if the corresponding cell in `matrix2` is an `x` and keep the original number if it is another letter.

I should get

*New_matrix1*

```
  1  2  3  4 
A 1  0  0  0
B 1  0  0  1
C 0  0  1  0
D 0  1  1  0
```

Does someone have an idea?

**matrix1**

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

**matrix2**

```
structure(c("a", "b", "x", "0", "0", "0", "0", "c", "0", "x", 
"a", "b", "x", "a", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

Comment: @markus I added the dput

Comment: If a value is `0` in the `matrix1` and the corresponding cell in `matrix2` is an `x`, then the answer you accepted will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
m1 - (m2 == "x")
#  1 2 3 4
#A 1 0 0 0
#B 1 0 0 1
#C 0 0 1 0
#D 0 1 1 0
```

**data**

```
m1 <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                  1L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C", 
                                                                    "D"), c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
m2 <- structure(c("a", "b", "x", "0", "0", "0", "0", "c", "0", "x", 
                  "a", "b", "x", "a", "0", "0"), .Dim = c(4L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                    c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
m1[m2 == "x"] <- 0
m1

#   1 2 3 4
# A 1 0 0 0
# B 1 0 0 1
# C 0 0 1 0
# D 0 1 1 0
```